# Returning the username as is in the SAML assertion in Shibboleth IDPV3.3

Tags: shibboleth

I am using Shibboleth IDPv3.3 to integrate with our SP and I was able to get the SSO authentication with LDAP working.

However I am seeing the NameID which is a generated one and not the one I entered during authentication

```
 <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
                          NameQualifier="https://shib.nslab.com/idp/shibboleth"
                          SPNameQualifier="https://chandracppm.nslab.com/networkservices/saml2/sp"
                          >7DBQ2seeNYvP9l6RsCrJZRh8/kw=</saml2:NameID>
```

For our SP we want the actual username that the user entered in the login page to be returned as the NameID.

What is the configuration I need to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Shibboleth IDP v3.3 to return the username entered as NameID in the SAML response by doing the following

In the attribute-resolver.conf

```
<AttributeDefinition id="uid" xsi:type="PrincipalName">
    <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:uid" encodeType="false" />
    <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML2String" name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" friendlyName="uid" encodeType="false" />
</AttributeDefinition>
```

in the SP Metadata specifying the NameID format

```
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
```

In the saml-nameid.xml

Commenting out all other beans except

```
 <util:list id="shibboleth.SAML2NameIDGenerators">
<bean parent="shibboleth.SAML2AttributeSourcedGenerator"
        p:format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
        p:attributeSourceIds="#{ {'uid'} }" />
```

With these 3 pieces of configuration and making sure that attribute-filter is set to release all the attributes I was able to populate the UserID entered by the user in the Shibboleth IDP as the  in the response assertion.